# SystemVerilog errors

Tags: system-verilog

Error: (vlog-13069) C:\Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a\examples\tb.sv(192): near "(": syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ';' or ','.

I don't know what happened.Same code works well on Aldec.

```
program automatic process (dut_io.TB a);            
parameter CLK_CYCLE=40;
parameter num_data=16;
......


endprogram

process process_instance (dut_io.TB);    //here shows the error
```

Answer (score 2):

`process` is a built-in class in SystemVerilog. See [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 9.7 *Fine-grain process control* and Annex G.6 *Process*. Rename your `process` to a non-reserved word, for example `myProcess`.

The `dut_io.TB` in `program automatic process (dut_io.TB a);` should be an interface name (ex: `my_interface`)or interface name dot modport (ex: `my_interface.my_modport`. It should not be a hierarchical path to an instance of an interface.

Comment: Also, I thought ModelSim did not support program blocks - use a module instead. I don't reccomend using them anyways. See http://go.mentor.com/programblocks